# Determine if date is weekend or weekday

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

So I have an input field where you select a date by clicking on a calendar and then that date is filled into a field.

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="" class="form-control datepicker" disabled="">
```

This field is filled when a visitor clicks on the date on a calendar, the date is then passed through to the field above using javascript.

```
$("td").click(function(){
   var day =  $(this).find(".day").html();
   $(".datepicker").val("<?php echo $this->uri->segment('3'); ?>/"+day+"/<?php echo $this->uri->segment('2'); ?>");
});
```

To create a `value` of something like this for example `07/14/2014`

Then I have a drop down with a certain set of times. This is the Weekday Time Schedule:

```
<select name="time" class="form-control">
   <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
   <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
   <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
   <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
</select>
```

I have a different time frame set for weekends. But I currently have no way to distinguish between what days are weekdays and what days are weekends in the date field.

I am using codeigniter to generate the calendar and the form. So my dropdown looks like this:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('time', $week_times, '', 'class="form-control"'); ?>
```

$week_times need to be converted into an if statement, something like the below so that I can provide two different sets of times based on what day of the week the day falls on for that month.

```
if(date == weekday){
   $times = $week_times;
}
elseif(date == weekend){
   $times = $week_end_times;
}
```

Obviosuly, that isn't a real if statement, but if I had that I wouldn't be asking the question **How can I tell if a date field is a weekday or weekend and choose an array based off that information?**

Comment: weekends are supposed to be `saturdays and sundays` right? just check the day of the date according to users input. [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). then just have your preset time values (array) according to that day

Comment: Yes, weekends are `Saturday and Sunday` and weekdays are `Monday through Friday` `"just check what day it is today."` The date selected may not be todays date though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a helper in CI so that it can be used commonly, and add :

```
function is_weekend($your_date) {
    $week_day = date('w', strtotime($your_date));
    //returns true if Sunday or Saturday else returns false
    return ($week_day == 0 || $week_day == 6);
}
```

and use it

```
if( is_weekend($date) ) {
    //its weekend do something
}
else {
    //its not weekend
}
```

Comment: So `$your_date` would be 07/14/2014 right? or just `07/14`

Comment: you need to give full date as 07/14/2014